# JMeter: Using a regex extractor value in beanshell post processor to extract a value using it in another threads

Tags: jmeter

I managed to set a script to extract value from token and using it globally for other thread but unfortunately, my script is extracting value as 1 by default.

[BeanShell PreProcessor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qn0eM.png)

[Regular Expression Extractor + logs printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZECf.png)

My expectation is to print the value extracted from the token request .

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer why your script always extracts the value 1 till we know what is the response returned and how your `Regex Extractor` is behaving on this response. Also it is better to use `Groovy` in newer versions of JMeter instead of `BeanShell`.

As an example to help you, I have posted below the usage of `Regex Extractor` and `Beanshell Preprocessor` for one of my old projects which extracts a `cookie & CSRF` values from the response of the previous request and passes on to the next request.

**HTTP Response:**

`{"responseMessage":{"messageObjects":[{"Authorization":"Bearer eyJhbGcxxxxxxxxxx.hsagdshvvdcwfdhwegdwdvbsqmshljkdhlqwkvnAJHFDBVGHWFHJDWBMNEHDJBSMNWBWJLHDKLJWHKJHDHWFVWDJGJKEWWBDNXVWGHDFWJHXKLBSNXVWFXWJEHXKWBXWDVXHGHWCDGXWDXCB0YXNrdcbwdgwegvcbwdvxbscxwfdvcwehgdwebwbvdcwdgckkhecdADGGHWFCVWBDVCGWCWVXNBSVXKWHCWVCBWCJWFGHECWECwgdhwvcwehhebdmnwwjhgnwvdcnbvwgvcwrehcwefnwecwghkevwe.abcdefghijklmnopqrst-poushfgabjwgjhwdvvttrudyqgd-CSGQGBkjgdjwhged","csrfToken":"adganm7ik39i6oclabce54154","ConnectedIP":"127.0.0.1","lastLoginIp":"null"}],"messageString":""},"responseStatus":200}`

**Regular Expression Extractor** (Name of the variable used is "authcsrfkey")

`{"responseMessage":{"messageObjects":\[{"Authorization":(.+?),"csrfToken":"(.+?)"`

**BeanShell PostProcessor** (as I need to join the two extracted values. This postprocessor is just after the Regex Extractor)

```
String authkey=vars.get("authcsrfkey_g1");
String csrf=vars.get("authcsrfkey_g2");
String cookie="Authorization=" + authkey + "; csrfToken=" + csrf;
vars.put("cookie",cookie);
```

**BeanShell PreProcessor** (to be added in the header of the subsequent request)

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;
sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new Header("Cookie",vars.get("cookie")));
```