# How can i get data from Jmeter log viewer and send into another next request

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hADaC.png) . I decoded a token using JSR223 Post Processor and able to see correct decoded token in the log viewer using "log.info(vars.get(mystring));". Now I want to get that decoded data to send in another next request. So how I can do it?

I used following code to decode token and[enter image description here][2] print in the JMeter log viewer-

```
enter code here String a=vars.get("tokenid");
import encrypt.TokenUpdate;
TokenUpdate obj=new TokenUpdate();
String mystring=obj.enc(a);
log.info(mystringenter image description here);
log.info(vars.get(mystring));
```

decoded data is showing in the JMeter log viewer. So ho can I get that data and to send into another next request?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hADaC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `vars.put` and reference the variable in your next subsequent request.

Example below:

```
String a=vars.get("tokenid");
import encrypt.TokenUpdate;
TokenUpdate obj=new TokenUpdate();
String mystring=obj.enc(a);
log.info(vars.get(mystring));
vars.put("YourVariableName",mystring);
```

Now in your next subsequent sampler you can refer the variable like `${YourVariableName}`

You can refer my other detailed answer on same topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55436549/jmeter-using-a-regex-extractor-value-in-beanshell-post-processor-to-extract-a-v/55447865#55447865)

Comment: Great, it helped you. Please acknowledge by accepting the answer.